# Which slots can roll which affixes?

Tags: diablo-iii

Certain affixes can only appear in certain slots, for example, CD only ever rolls on gloves, rings, amulets and weapons, Obviously, legendaries are an exception to this. Some you can find, for example for CD: http://www.diablowiki.net/Critical_hit_damage, but for others, like +Damage from certain skills I cannot find anywhere.

What are the slots that *Increases Meteor damage by x%* can roll on? More generally, what are the slots that any given stats can roll on?

Comment: this might help http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/82397-list-of-skill-dmg-and-elemental-dmg-affixes

Comment: @z- That's perfect, want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [up to date list on diablofans](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/82397-list-of-skill-dmg-and-elemental-dmg-affixes) that has a complete list of possible gear boosts.

In particular, the only slots that can roll meteor are head, boots, and source.

Comment: This link is helpful for elemental damage and skill damage but what about the other affixes ?

Comment: @WizLiz the other affixes are pretty standard and can be found via the wiki.  Its only the skill and element ones that are confusing and specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask this question to reroll at mystic, you can see all possible affix just besfore rerolling an affix.

Open the mystic, put the item in mystic socket. You now have to choose an affix to reroll. Without choosing any, you can click on the "?" next to the affix to see all possible reroll. (By experience, certains affix have way more chance to be rolled than others, particularly the primary carac and Vit carac)

It can also tell you which affix can be rolled on each item (even legendary), which is nice.

Comment: I'm thinking about making a quick and dirty possible solution (think http://www.wow-gem.com/gems.aspx, but for affixes) for just this kind of question/answer)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what you meant, because I don't know Wow and didn't understand your link well, but if it can help, yeah go ahead :D

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer an alternative, I always use [d3maxstats.com](http://www.d3maxstats.com/affixes/) for this kind of information. It allows you to select class, gear layout and whether to show the values associated with Ancient versions or not. Basically, You select multiple affixes and it'll show you on what slots they can roll and what their maximum value for each suffix is, including legendary only affixes such as +elemental damage on `Stone of Jordan`.

Comment: I'm not sure this resource was around back when I posted this. Thanks for updating.